# How use thenEmpty and then thenReturn in Spring WebFlux?

Tags: spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I'm new in Spring WebFlux and I have a problem. I want to return something like `Mono<String>` as follow:

```
@PostMapping("/test")
public Mono<String> test(){
    return Mono.just("Test String")
           .thenEmpty(it -> {
                // Do something I need
                System.out.println("Print somethings");
           })
           .thenReturn("Return String");
}
```

I wish the method to return `Return String`, But it return nothing. What's the Problem?

Comment: it seems java but right now it does not compile

Comment: @firegloves Sorry I use `kotlin` and tried to covert to java, But it may have error

Comment: if you need help in kotlin why don't you post in kotlin?

Comment: @firegloves because There are few people who know kotlin. I fixed the bug.

Comment: why do you want to empty your mono? there is a reason? have you read the behaviour of thenEmpty? what do you need exactly?

Comment: @firegloves Because I do somthings such as saving a record, logs and etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try something like this:

```
   @PostMapping("/test") public Mono<String> test(){
        return Mono.just("Test String")
                .doOnNext(s -> {
                    // do what you want
                })
                .map(s -> {
                    return "done";
                });
   }
```

You can use other `doOn*` methods, depending on what you need. For example `doOnSuccess` or `doOnError`.

Then you can use `map` if you need to manipulate your data (but keeping return type).

Answer (score 2):

thenEmpty will be invoked and return Mono<Void> as part of pipeline order. since Mono<Void> return, rest of the operator in pipeline is not working. if you want to use thenReturn then use below code.

```
@PostMapping("/test")
public Mono<String> test(){
    return Mono.just("Test String")
           .doOnNext(s -> {
                    // do what you want
                })
           .thenReturn("Return String");
}
```